# AR Foundation - Place a prefab with 2 touches on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm developing an augmented reality app for construction industry and need to place a model in 1:1 scale. I know how to place with one touch, but I would like to know if it is possible to set 2 points to anchor my model.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What are these two points supposed to do?

Comment: to define where my model will spawn. I need to control exactly where the 3D object is located

Comment: Yeah sure but ... describe what your two positions are supposed to do .. how exactly is the interaction supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if (Input.touchCount == 1)` to detect more than just one finger tap (at the same time). Then you can place your object based on the two-finger touch.

```
            // Store both touches.
            Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);
            // Calculate previous position
            Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
            Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;
            // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
            float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
            float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;
            // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
            float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;
            float pinchAmount = deltaMagnitudeDiff * 0.02f * Time.deltaTime;
            spawnedObject.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(pinchAmount, pinchAmount, pinchAmount);
            // Clamp scale
            float Min = 0.005f;
            float Max = 3f;
            spawnedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                Mathf.Clamp(spawnedObject.transform.localScale.x, Min, Max),
                Mathf.Clamp(spawnedObject.transform.localScale.y, Min, Max),
                Mathf.Clamp(spawnedObject.transform.localScale.z, Min, Max)
            );
```